# Question about darboux integral sums and inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I am working through part of my book which deals with area of curvilinear trapezoid.

I am getting this inequality $s\leq P_1 \leq P_2 \leq S$ where $s=\sum_{n=1}^n m_i \Delta x_i$

$S=\sum_{n=1}^n M_i \Delta x_i$ which are respectively darboux lower and upper integral sums.For answering question you don't need to know what is $P_1,P_2$ here.

Then book says because $f$ is integrable then $I=\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is only number that regardless of split will satisfy $s \leq I \leq S$.

I know that $s \leq I \leq S$ but I can't understand from where we got that it is only number between those?

Comment: Omitted from question:  All possible (s,S) pairs,  all possible $(\Delta x_i)$ divisions?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sorry for misconception.Yes all possible pairs and divisions.

Comment: I presume if there is an $I'\ne I$, you can show $I'\gt S$ or $I'\lt s$ for soome division.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I think I got the answer.We know that $lim_{\lambda\to 0}s=I_1$ $lim_{\lambda\to 0}S=I_2$ (if f is bounded).And because $f$ is integrable which means that $I_1=I_2=I$ and $s \leq S$ from this I think follows that it is only number

Comment: Writing infinite sums for $s$ and $S$ is certainly incorrect. The correct statement is that $f$ is integrable on the interval if and only if there is a unique number (namely the integral) lying between lower sum and upper sum for every possible partition.

Comment: @TedShifrin It was silly mistake,my explanation is correct?

Comment: You don't have an explanation. Uniqueness is the definition of integrability. Some books say that the infimum of the upper sums is equal to the supremum of lower sums. This is equivalent to my statement.

Comment: @TedShifrin So we can't prove that it is unique?

Comment: If you *know* the function is integrable (e.g., if it's continuous), then you get uniqueness. It sounds to me like the little bit you quote from your book says that you are assuming that, yes, the function is integrable.